# Salesforce CASESAFEID(Id): Last 03 digits of all the record ids are coming up same

Tags: salesforce

I am testing CASESAFEID(Id) function to get the 18-digit ids in my report. I created a formula field and used that field in a report. I am noticing that the last 03 characters of most of the records in this field are the same. I could not find the reason or logic for these 03 characters on google search to posting it here.

My formula field:
[image]

My report:
[image]

I am using trailhead playground for this testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that can happen. IDs that have uppercase letters on same positions will have same 3 "digit" suffix. You don't have to worry about that? There are some posts if you're really interested in the algorithm.

https://astadiaemea.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/15-or-18-character-ids-in-salesforce-com-%E2%80%93-do-you-know-how-useful-unique-ids-are-to-your-development-effort/

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/what-are-salesforce-ids-composed-of

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/field_types.htm (scroll down to ID field type)

Answer (score 1):

They're essentially a checksum-type value to ensure that valid Salesforce Ids do not differ from one another *only in case*. This provides safety for tools like Excel that treat `abc` and `AbC` as the same value.

The behavior you are observing is normal. There's no need to test this formula function as such; it's a standard part of the platform.